# wrap text inside <nobr> tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have sharepoint gererate lable which is in `<nobr>` tag. But on the page it is so long I need to wrap this using jquery.

```
<td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader">
    <nobr>On a scale of 1 to 10, with 1 being the lowest and 10 the highest, please rate your overall satisfaction with the management and implementation of this project?  Rating:</nobr>
</h3></td>
```

Better option is remove `<nobr>` tag. Is it possible to remove based on text? because there are other so many other `<nobr>` tags on the page.

Comment: I'm really confused as to what you are trying to do here.  It sounds like you should just be using a `<p>` tag instead of `<nobr>` tag.

Comment: @James, It is sharepoint generated page. I dont have control on html generation. only option is tweak after page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
$('.ms-formlabel nobr').css('white-space', 'normal');
```

The `<nobr>` tag usually has a CSS `white-space` of `nowrap`.

Comment: This is working fine. It is making very short wrap. I need some width. it is making around 6 rows. I just need 2 or 3 rows wrap.

Comment: You will have to add the width to the outer element (the `.ms-formlabel` element.) I would recommend trying to change the `width` of the `td` to be 100% and see how that looks.

Comment: 100% is showing full length. I used 500px. it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove **nobr** tag and **keep the text** you should

```
var text = $(".ms-formlabel nobr").html()
$(".ms-formlabel h3").html(text);
```

If you just want to remove the **nobr** tag and remove the text just:

```
$(".ms-formlabel nobr").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it sounds like you are forced into receiving `<nobr>` tags.  If I were you, I'd just convert them to `<p>` tags then.

```
$('nobr').each(function() {
    $(this).after('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>');
    $(this).remove();
});
```

If you only want to keep the text inside of them, then use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.  You could alternatively use `<div />` instead of the `<p />` tags.